# LaTeX glossary doesn't typeset (AucTeX)

Tags: auctex

Consider the following LaTeX file (named `test.tex`) demonstrating the use of the `glossaries-extra` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},description={potato}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\glsadd{potato}potahto
\printglossaries
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

When I compile the document with `C-c, C-a`, the following output results.

[image: Glossary error]

What do I need to do in order for the document to typeset properly?

Comment: If `TeX-command-run-all` is still sufficiently close to (my) original implementation the next command to run is determined through `TeX-command-default` (which see).

Comment: Could we close this question as duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/48293/2370 ? (I see this one as application of the other one. Is that right?)

Comment: @Tobias: I guess you can, even though they're not really duplicates.